# Link Collection Menu Item

Tags: category-blog

I think I'm just overlooking something.

**What I got:** At the moment, there's a menu entry which shows a `category blog`, so basically, it lists all contents from this category.

**What I'm looking for:** I want this page to not only link to posts, but also link to something external as well as a shop category in the Hikashop module. Basically, I just want to see a page formatted like the category blog, but with links to arbitrary pages, not only posts in one category.

How would I go about doing this? Am I maybe tackling the issue from a wrong perspective? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure which tags to use here, let me know if you have a better idea.

Comment: @MirkoMikan thanks for your suggestion. I will try to reshape my question tomorrow for better understanding. I do apologize if I'm talking weird stuff, I'm quite new to joomla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest creating modules for each of the non-article items you wish to include on the page and then insert the modules into an article.

**Category Blog**

Create an "Articles - Category" module and enter "category-blog" or similar as a custom module position name.

**External Link**

Add external links as normal in your article.

**Hikashop Category Module**

Enter "shop-category" or similar as a custom module position name for your Hikashop module.

**Joomla Article**

In the Joomla article, you can combine the modules in whatever order you like as follows by inserting them using the `loadposition` plugin and the custom module position names you have already created:

```
[Heading]

{loadposition category-blog}

[External Link]

{loadposition shop-category}

[any other content you like]
```

Remember to assign your modules to the appropriate menu item(s) that display your article.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure which one to accept now because I believe you both give valid strategies for my issue... Going to think about that tomorrow when I'm working on the project again

Comment: @Yorrd I won't get upset if you change your selected answer :) Neil's answer is more specific than mine.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are a number of ways you could go about achieving such a page.

1. Create an article and manually add everything yourself (Not very
   efficient).
2. Use something like [Nonumber's Articles Anywhere](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/articlesanywhere#multiple-articles). It allows you to add articles by category and other methods, so you should be able to customize it the way you like.(Slightly more efficient then option1). In this case, you would probably need the pro version.
3. [Create an override.](https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla) This involves a bit of programming, so might be considered harder than the first 2 options, but is probably the best option. I won't go into specifics, but hopefully this be enough to get you started.

Comment: This gave me the perspective I needed. I'll try to create an override tomorrow. I might have questions, but that's for another thread. Thanks!